# Syntax highlighting of C function calls in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I use a custom syntax highlighting theme for C in emacs, but I'm missing the possibility of highlighting function calls. For example:

```
int func(int foo)
{
    return foo;
}

void main()
{
    int bar = func(3);
}
```

Is there any way to highlight the call to "func" in this example?
It doesn't matter if macros are highlighted too. Keywords like if, switch or sizeof should not match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of entries in the keyword list is significant. So if you put your entries after the ones that highlight keywords and function declarations, these won't be matched.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
  '(("\\(\\w+\\)\\s-*\("
    (1 rumpsteak-font-lock-function-call-face)))
  t)
```

Alternatively, you can use a function instead of a regexp as the `MATCHER`. Overkill for your question if you've stated your requirements exactly, but useful in harder cases. Untested (typed directly in the browser, in fact, so I don't even guarantee balanced parentheses).

```
(defun rumpsteak-match-function-call (&optional limit)
  (while (and (search-forward-regexp "\\(\\w+\\)\\s-*\(" limit 'no-error)
              (not (save-match-data
                     (string-match c-keywords-regexp (match-string 1))))
              (not (save-excursion
                     (backward-char)
                     (forward-sexp)
                     (c-skip-whitespace-forward)
                     (or (eobp) (= ?\{ (char-after (point)))))))))
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
  '((rumpsteak-match-function-call
    (1 rumpsteak-font-lock-function-call-face))))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
                   '(("\\<\\([a-zA-Z_]*\\) *("  1 font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

in your .emacs.  Replace font-lock-keyword-face by the one you want (M-X list-faces-display to get a list of predefined one).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any way to avoid matching function declarations and keywords?

Comment: It's probably possible but I don't know how without looking at the documentation.  Start with C-H F and gives font-lock-add-keywords as function (C-H V to ask help for a variable, font-lock-keywords being one other candidate starting point).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ctrl-s for searching or Ctrl-r for searching backward. Emacs will highlight your function for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to permanently color all function calls as part of a coloring theme.